# Сравнительный анализ текста в Python

Tags: python-3.x, синтаксический-анализ, лексический-анализатор

Коллеги, добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие библиотеки в Python могут помочь в решении задачи? К примеру у меня есть строка, которая состоит из 10 слов. Назовем ее "идеальный шаблон". Есть таблица с десятками тысяч подобных идеальному шаблону строк, но в этих строках все же присутствует отклонение от идеала. Задача вычислить процент соответствия каждой строки массива идеальному шаблону. Подскажите куда смотреть? Решение ищу в Python 3, если это важно.

Это решение я ищу для анализа базы данных на предмет чистого и корректного заполнения данных этой базы. То есть, анализ строк на предмет лишних символов, отсутствия значений или неполного заполнения полей.

Comment: Расстояние Левенштейна, думаю, подойдет...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, спасибо!